# How do I send structured data (XML) & a .docx from a website POST to a c# desktop app

Tags: c#, php, web-services, rest, soap

I have a C# desktop application that is coded in Visual Studio, and a website that asks for 20 fields of information and allows the user to attach a .pdf or a .docx file. I have an XML parser that I wrote that takes in a single user's information, and processess it and uses it on the C# application. The .pdf and .docx are bundled in the same folder as the XML, so I can just call the path of the .pdf and .docx files to use them.

I was thinking that the XML is to be made with a PHP script that just executes on a button press, and then saves it in a loction on the website's server. The C# tool needs to be able to get that folder and get the XML and download the .pdf and .docx if needed.

I've never combined cross platform and this is a greenfield project that I am using the Selenium C# web-automation library to automate using data from each XML. It would finish processing the XML, do a 8 hour long loop of processing, then take the next XML in a queue if needed.

I would like to understand how I could go from a form from a website to a C# application. Returning a response isn't really needed, but to know which order the XML document is at in the queue of XMLs being processed would be worked on after.

SOAP/Restful tech seems to be a good idea in this since I think I wouldn't need to reinvent the wheel here, but they both seem to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you need to send a file cross platform, you can send a byte stream by encoding and deconding it as follows:

C# Encode

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\file.pdf");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

C# Decode

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);
File.WriteAllBytes("c:\file.pdf", bytes);
```

PHP Encode

```
$b64Doc = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents("c:\file.pdf")));
```

PHP Decode

```
$pdf_base64 = "base64string";
//Get File content from txt file
$pdf_base64_handler = fopen($pdf_base64,'r');
$pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($pdf_base64));
fclose ($pdf_base64_handler);
//Decode pdf content
$pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
//Write data back to pdf file
$pdf = fopen ('"c:\file.pdf','w');
fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
//close output file
fclose ($pdf);
echo 'Done';
```

Comment: This seems excellent if I was hosting the website on the same computer. The website that run the php script is elsewhere, and I would just be able to access the /private directories of the /root of that website. This seems excellent, but I need to figure out how to connect a web site form into the c#. I think I'm missing how the decode works, as that I think is how I need it to read the file. Thanks